# JMeter JSON Extractor to get value by condition

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, extract

I get a `JSON` string like this:

```
[{"id":123,"name":"XX","default":false,"type":"other"},{"id":789,"name":"ZZ","default":false,"type":"first"}]
```

I would like to get `id`, where name is `ZZ`, so extracted value should be `789`.
I tried with this JSON expression:

`$.id[?(@.name=='ZZ')]`

I tried with regular expression too:

`{"id":(.+?),"name":"ZZ","default":false`,

My regular expression solution isn't working, because there are similar `name` values, like `ZZ` and `ZZ (XYZ)`.

Comment: Use a `JSON` parser instead.

Comment: @Jan : Do you mean `BeanShell`?

Comment: See https://eclipsesource.com/de/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, with JSON extractor you need to find ZZ and then get the id of the object return, use the following expression:

```
[?(@.name == 'ZZ')].id
```

Comment: This expression isn't match for me, I get empty string.

Comment: It's working for me with JSON Extractor, maybe you show only part of JSON response?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in jmeter 4.0 version its okay to use $..token_id, but in jmeter 2.x version we need to use $.token_id i.e, there should be only one dot(.) after $, i faced the issue and now its working.